# Iteration moves the cursor in PyMongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

Not sure what's happening here or why, it seems as if when I iterate on a cursor it moves it, because I can't run a second loop from the same starting point. My example:

```
players = db.player.find({'parent_api__id' : 'stats', 'game__id':{'$in':games_list}, "played":"true"});

count = 0;
for c in players:
    count = count + 1

for c in players:
    game = db.game.find_one({'parent_api__id':'schedule', 'id':c['game__id']})
    c['date'] = game['scheduled']
    print c
```

In this one it never enters the second loop, if I put a print up top it never hits it, and it never does the print c at the bottom

Now if I comment out the loop with the count in it, so it looks like this:

```
players = db.player.find({'parent_api__id' : 'stats', 'game__id':{'$in':games_list}, "played":"true"});

#count = 0;
#for c in players:
#   count = count + 1

for c in players:
    game = db.game.find_one({'parent_api__id':'schedule', 'id':c['game__id']})
    c['date'] = game['scheduled']
    print c
```

then it enters the 2nd loop and iterates completely fine (printing out as it goes along)

Why is this? do I have to reset the cursor every time in between with another players = db.player.find({'parent_api__id' : 'stats', 'game__id':{'$in':games_list}, "played":"true"}); ? Seems like that can't be the way it was intended.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: This is the standard [`Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) pattern as used in Python and other languages. It seems unusual to iterate the result set twice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a cursor (by definition) points to the next item (document in case of Mongo) once the current item is iterated over, the cursor itself provides an iterator function and internally maintains a pointer to the items that have been "consumed".

There are two approaches to solve the problem you are facing,

- First is to use the cursor's [`rewind()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.rewind) method to set the cursor to its unevaluated original state
- Second, clone the cursor using [`clone()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.clone), which will give you a second cursor that will be an exact clone of the first one, but will be a completely new instance. Use this if you need to maintain states of the two cursors throughout or at the end of evaluation.

Comment: Note that both of these options can result in diverging result sets, which may not be what @Synt4x is expecting. These are both variations of a cursor reset: `rewind()` resets the cursor so the query will be reevaluated with the same options; `clone()` creates a new (unevaluated) cursor with the same options. If you want to iterate the *same* data it would be best to iterate in a single loop.

Comment: @Stennie your right I shouldn't have to iterate twice I can do it all within 1 loop I had them separate to test the data was accurate before I iterated on it to push it into a Mongo collection but now I can consolidate into one.

Comment: @Stennie at the same time though just to be clear, neither rewind() or clone() should give me diverging data sets unless I modify the set through my first loop correct? Or is there a time where I could rewind() my cursor after the first loop through and say it hit... 23,650 elements, and the second time through it will hit a different number?   (same thing w/ clone())

Comment: @Synt4x not necessarily modified by the first loop, if you have other methods that write into the same collection concurrently there is a possibility that the cursor in the second loop will iterate over a different result.